# DOM traversal by CSS class. Syntactical error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-traversal

Question answered: How would I find the nearest div by searching for it's css class.

My script is below, the line in question is the "var panel line", I am wanting to know how to reference the nearest object with the CSS class, ".panel" and change it to be visible. I think this is a syntax error of some sort but if it's something else let me know. I'm pretty new to this kind of code so I appreciate any extra tid bits or advice. Thanks!

--code below--

```
                <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("navpop");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.closest('.panel');
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

[note: Extra code (HTML, CSS) was removed from this question after it was answered because I do not feel it is necessary or helpful for others who come to this post; if you want to see it the rest of the code is available if you click the edits button]

Comment: What is your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: I am trying to reference the nearest html block of html code with the class .panel

Comment: If there is a syntax error, post the (exact) error message. If there is no error message, there is no syntax error. Also, you should strongly consider using `let` instead of `var`, especially with anything asynchronous.

Comment: OK; what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to reference the nearest html block of html code with the class .panel however this script isn't finding the block of code which contains ".panel" as a class and I want to know how I would do that. Would it help to see the HTML?                                                                                                                   Also, CertainPerformance could you elaborate more on why you would use let as well as explain how the let function works for me? Much appreciated!

Comment: @SchadeM it would, there's different definitions for `the nearest object with the CSS class, ".panel"`

Comment: Okay, give me a moment.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: I am grabbing the CSS right now as well.

Comment: `closest()` "returns the closest ancestor..." But it doesn't seem that `.panel` is an ancestor of `.navpop`, so I don't think `closest()` is what you're looking for. Can you help clarify your HTML structure? It seems there is an opening `<div>` missing at the top.

Comment: This is just a part of the code, not the whole thing (explaining your div) how would  I return something that isn't an ancestor or a child?

Comment: It depends on your structure. One idea is to traverse to a common ancestor using [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and then use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to find the associated `.panel` descendant. Another idea is to use an ID to reference the panel directly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you show dev! I looked up querySelector and eventually came across some other properties which led me to a solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, document.queryselector('class') will find all sections of code containing a specified class. This W3 article explains related properties to DOM traversal across none-related sections of code. [awesome w3 article link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Okay, with help from showdev's suggestion to look into other properties like query selector I have solved my problem. After researching that property I came across the document and queryselector function which will find and execute on all divs in a document containing a specified class as defined below.

Many thanks to showdev for suggesting the queryselector function. 
(be sure to up-vote his comment as he contributed to this answer)

The script below is my successful solution:

```
        <!--Collapsing Button-->
        <div>
            <button class="navpop"> </button>


                <!--Java-Script-->
            <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("navpop");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = document.querySelector('.panel');
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Really excited I was able to solve this cause I was stuck on it for a few days so I really appreciate your help showdev!